# Const как поменять значение через Edit Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Как сделать, чтобы параметры `LAT`, `RUS`, `LengthLAT`, `LengthRUS`, `LengthNUM` и `MAX_NUMBER` принимали значения с `Edit`?

```
const
      LAT = 'test1';  // массив латинских прописных букв
      RUS = 'test2';  // массив русских строчных букв
      LengthLAT = 2;          // кол-во латинских букв
      LengthRUS = 7;          // кол-во русских букв
      LengthNUM = 1;          // кол-во цифр 
      MAX_NUMBER = 9;         // максимальное цифровое число
    var
      i: integer;   // переменная для счетчика
      password: string;  // переменная для хранения
    begin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему именно константа, а не глобальная переменная?
Но если хочется именно константу изменять, то можно использовать директиву `{$WRITEABLECONST ON/OFF}`:

```
const
  {$WRITEABLECONST ON}
  const_value: Integer = 5;
  {$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
....
 const_value := IntToStrDef(Edit1.Text, 10);
```

Посмотрите [справку](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirswriteabletypedconstants_xml.html) по этой директиве.

Comment: А как же подключить 6 моих значений: Через edit1, edit2, edit3, edit4, edit5, edit6. Чего то запуталась я.

Comment: Что Вам мешает применить мой ответ к своему коду?

Comment: Сейчас буду разбираться.

Comment: На всякий случай поругаю, негоже использовать WRITEABLECONST, тем самым превращая константы в обычные переменные. Тогда уж переменными их и надо объявлять.

Comment: @Kromster, собственно я и задал вопрос Татьяне, почему константа, а не глобальная переменная. Но раз вопрос звучал "как изменить константу", то на это и дал ответ.

Comment: @dr.F.I.N. спасибо за ответ. Мой комментарий скорее относился к ответу, а не к вам или к вопросу. ИМХО это необходимое уточнение - в духе "для переменных нужно использовать переменные, но если вы так настаиваете, то .." ) *ТС ответ может и не даст, а ваш ответ будут читать еще десятки и сотни других людей ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Поменять:

```
const
  LAT = 'test1';  // массив латинских прописных букв
  RUS = 'test2';  // массив русских строчных букв
  LengthLAT = 2;          // кол-во латинских букв
  LengthRUS = 7;          // кол-во русских букв
  LengthNUM = 1;          // кол-во цифр 
  MAX_NUMBER = 9;         // максимальное цифровое число
var
  i: integer;   // переменная для счетчика
  password: string;  // переменная для хранения
```

На:

```
var
  LAT: string = 'test1';  // массив латинских прописных букв
  RUS: string = 'test2';  // массив русских строчных букв
  LengthLAT: integer = 2;          // кол-во латинских букв
  LengthRUS: integer = 7;          // кол-во русских букв
  LengthNUM: integer = 1;          // кол-во цифр 
  MAX_NUMBER: integer = 9;         // максимальное цифровое число
  i: integer;   // переменная для счетчика
  password: string;  // переменная для хранения

...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LAT:= Edit1.Text; //Меняем значение переменной LAT на Edit1
  RUS:= Edit2.Text; //Меняем значение переменной RUS на Edit2

  //Если нужно наоборот
  //Edit1.Text:= LAT;
  //Edit2.Text:= RUS
end;
```

Учите матчасть, В большинство языках программирования const является квалификатором типа: ключевое слово применяется к типу данных, показывая, что данные константны неизменяемы.

Comment: @Татьяна, при объявлении глобальной переменной можно задать начальное значение. Локальной, насколько знаю, нет.

Comment: Обновил ответ, забыл указать тип переменной

Comment: А теперь если не сложно подскажите как значения 'test1' и 'test2' заменить на Edit1 и Edit2. Что бы можно было менять значения.